# Informação de um User Control até o Window pai

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou tentando enviar umas informações de meu User Control até a barra de titulo da tela principal que seria o janela pai.
A informação que estou tentando enviar, é a empresa selecionada de um DataGrid.

Como posso fazer isso? não estou conseguindo..
Espero qualquer ajuda...

Class onde eu armazeno a informação capturado;

```
public class EmpresaSelecionada
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
    }

    public int Codigo
    {
        get { return es.Codigo; }
        set { es.Codigo = value; }
    }
```

Onde eu gravo:

```
es = new EmpresaSelecionada();

Object item = dataGridEmpresa.SelectedItem;

string codigo = (dataGridEmpresa.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;

es.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(codigo);
```

Onde eu tento recuperar para jogar em minha TextBlock da tela principal:

```
Telas.EscolherEmpresa.EmpresaSelecionada es = new Telas.EscolherEmpresa.EmpresaSelecionada();

    public int Codigo = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        es = new Telas.EscolherEmpresa.EmpresaSelecionada();
        Codigo = es.Codigo;
    }

    private string _titulo;// = Convert.ToString(Codigo);
    public string Titulo
    {
        get
        {
            return _titulo;
        }
        set
        {
            _titulo = Convert.ToString(Codigo);
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Titulo,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isto de forma elegante, eu montei um exemplo para você. Vou descrever por partes:

Primeiramente no seu projeto você deve ter um modelo para `Empresa`, abaixo está o modelo básico que eu criei para exemplificar:

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string Fantasia { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1}",Codigo,Fantasia);
    }
}
```

Após isso criei um `UserControl` de exemplo chamado `MeuUserControl`. Abaixo o código `XAML` do **MeuUserControl.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MeuUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg_empresas" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding EmpresaSelecionada,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl},Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Empresas, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=UserControl}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codigo" Binding="{Binding Codigo}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Razão social" Binding="{Binding RazaoSocial}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fantasia" Binding="{Binding Fantasia}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A seguir o `CodeBehind` do **MeuUserControl.cs** (criei uma lista com empresas hipotéticas):

```
  public partial class MeuUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EmpresaSelecionadaProperty =
                               DependencyProperty.Register("EmpresaSelecionada", typeof(Empresa), typeof(MeuUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public Empresa EmpresaSelecionada
        {
            get{ return this.GetValue(EmpresaSelecionadaProperty) as Empresa; }
            set{ this.SetValue(EmpresaSelecionadaProperty, value); }
        }

        public List<Empresa> Empresas 
        {
            get 
            {
                return new List<Empresa>()
                {
                    new Empresa(){Codigo=1, RazaoSocial= "Razao Social 1", Fantasia="Fantasia 1"},
                    new Empresa(){Codigo=2, RazaoSocial= "Razao Social 2", Fantasia="Fantasia 2"},
                    new Empresa(){Codigo=3, RazaoSocial= "Razao Social 3", Fantasia="Fantasia 3"},
                    new Empresa(){Codigo=4, RazaoSocial= "Razao Social 4", Fantasia="Fantasia 4"},
                };
            }
        }

        public MeuUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

E por último o `XAML` da tela que utiliza o `UserControl`, cujo titulo é a empresa selecionada no `DataGrid`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="{Binding EmpresaSelecionada,ElementName=userControl,Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid>
        <controls:MeuUserControl x:Name="userControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A solução basicamente se resume em criar uma `DependencyProperty` no `UserControl` que esteja ligada com a `Empresa` selecionada no `DataGrid`, e ligar esta propriedade ao titulo da janela que utiliza o `UserControl`.

Comment: Esta solução foi útil para você?

Comment: Nicolas, mas como eu posso chamar esta empresa e jogar para o titulo? tentei com dois cliques sobre o item do DataGrid.. Mas não sei como chamá-lo

Comment: Como você pode notar o titulo da tela esta ligado com o item do datagrid selecionado, então com esta solução, sempre quanto o item selecionado no DataGrid mudar, automaticamente o titulo muda..Tente reproduzir o exemplo acima em um novo projeto, que consiguirás entender a solução.